# Facebook Scores API Global and Daily Rank on Unity

Tags: unity, facebook, leaderboards

I need to implement 4 types of leaderboards on my Unity game:

- All Time/Daily
- Global/Friends

I'm using Scores API from Facebook and I achieved All Time Friends Leaderboards. I'm taking a look at the [Scores API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements#scores) and I'm not seeing Daily nor Global rank anywhere.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and thinking a little, it is not reasonable facebook connect you with someone who's not on your social circle so it does not make any sense if Facebook made a global rank.

TL;DR Facebook don't have Global Rank

Comment: sorry. Completely forgot to mark as correct.